# Considering shopping for PC parts for my personal rig in Hong Kong. I would like to know about Indian import taxes

Tags: india, hong-kong, import-taxes

I found out there is 36.05% (Basic Customs duty @ 35% + Education Cess @3%) on the value of dutiable goods that is in excess of the Duty Free Allowance of 50000 rupee, according to 2016 Indian baggage rules.

Are there any other applicable taxes on top of this?

Comment: Please review your own question before submitting it. If you don't put any energy inte writing it then people wont put any energy into answering it either. I've now cleaned up your question a bit myself.

Comment: fair enough mikael i found some basic info http://www.referencer.in/Baggage_Rules/43_2016_Customs_N_T.aspx#corrigendum
i guess this much will do and thanks for your edit